# ASP.net This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, .net-4.0, pre-compilation

I am currently getting this when visiting my http:// websitehere.com/excelData.aspx page:

> This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!

The **file system directory on the server** looks like this:

```
--mainDir
 |--excelData.aspx
 |--PrecompiledApp.config
 |--Web.config
 |--bin
   |--App_Web_cuydkh1j.dll
   |--exceldata.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled
```

Not sure what I need to add/remove in order for it to display my page without that **precompilation tool text** on it.

The IIS server is version 6.1

Comment: Is ASP.Net registered to handle that "file" (.aspx)? If you look at the file itself (`excelData.aspx`), that is actually the only content. This means it was compiled as uneditable (fully compiled, html and all). I maybe bastardizing the term "pointer" but hope you get the idea. The (corresponding) file in the `/bin` is what needs to be executed (and isn't). Hth...

Answer (score 5):

One of the reasons for this problem is the file PrecompiledApp.config is missing from the root of your site (this file is generated by the publishing wizard).

Hope this help others.

Comment: PrecompiledApp.config is right there in his file list.

Answer (score 3):

*Problem:*
When you upload the web application, sometimes the most important files in the `bin` folder (e.g., the .dll files) will not upload correctly.

*Solution:*
Re-upload the bin folder. Remember to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the site is configured as an application on IIS